# Init value for a function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers, void, init

I have a simple question: how to give a function pointer a initial value, of kind of void..

```
typedef void (*FunctionPointer)();
FunctionPointer func; //how to init here
..... (func var may or may not be assigned a value here)
func()
```

So I want variable func to have an initial value, something like func = void() 
How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: `func = somefunction;` ?

Comment: that would of course work but I dont want to define a blank function for this simple purpose. I just want to have a neat solution.

Comment: Guess you are on your own then... unless you can find such a function that has no side-effects.

Comment: Blanc function: `void blanc(){}`

Comment: FunctionPointer func = NULL ?

Comment: it crashes if the var is assigned to NULL :(

Comment: Please do not hide away the pointer property in the typedef. Use `typedef void Function();` and `Function *func;`

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Maybe it's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, yes it is XY problem (I read the def):D. I guess the only way is to define a blank function then.

Comment: @hlovdal can you explain why it is not good to hide pointer property, currently I can:
`func = CustomFunc;`
but with your way I should do
`func = &CustomFunc;`

Comment: It should crash - this is the way to fix bugs. It looks like you want your program to continue working with uninitialized pointer.

Comment: See the question [http://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/23118](Typedef pointers a good idea?), and the answers are no.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared outside of any function already get initialized, you don't have to do anything.

If it is inside a function, then

```
FunctionPointer func = 0;
```